# Java JDK configurations on Mac

Tags: java, macos, configuration

I was messing with my terminal and deleted my java jdk and I have since downloaded a new jdk, I am just not sure where to put it and what environment variables to set.

When I run the command "javac test.java" I get

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/bin/javac"
```

My JAVA_HOME is set to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk
and the jdk is in that location

My question is where can I place my JDK so that my mac knows where to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Which JDK are you installing? The Oracle/Sun JDK installer DMG installs Java in the proper location (including the `/usr/bin` symlinks).

As an aside, use `/usr/libexec/java_home` to find out what your Mac thinks is the canonical JAVA_HOME.